# Filter messages by message_type in Yammer REST API

Tags: yammer

I'm developing Sharepoint portal homepage, and plan to show Yammer news (annoucements) on it.

I use get/messages/about_topic/[:id].json to get all messages by topic. I'm open to use another method thus. It may be from a topic, group or thread.

The problem is that all methods retrieve 20 last messages, no matter wich type of. As I don't need comments, I'm taking message_type == 'announcement' in my code.

Is there a way for better filtering, ideally during the initial request? According to documentation, about_topic method doesn't seem to have older_than parameter, and anyway I'd prefer avoid several queries (we expect a lot of comments, and several topics retrieved on the main page)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found myself a solution.

Using "threaded": true returns only first messages, without updates.

It's crazy that it's not in the method description.